# Wordpress space between text and tables

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress site: When I put a table to any page there is a big gap generated between text and table.

Please scroll down the page to see the problem.

Here is some of page code.

```
W trakcie studiów studenci zyskują więc doświadczenie zawodowe, którym można się pochwalić we własnym portfolio.</div>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" width="623">Lean User Experience &amp; product Design</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="417">Wprowadzenie do user experience design</td>
<td width="33">4h</td>
<td width="173">Iga Mościchowska</td>
</tr>
```

Here is backend screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IzBm.jpg)

Comment: there is a lot of bar tag in your code please remove  those

Comment: why do you have so many line breaks ( `<br>` )

Comment: No I have not. It is generęting automaticly.

Comment: How does it generate

Comment: Post the code that is generating the tables. It inserts a lot of `<br>` tags between `tr` and `td` elements.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any idea...

Comment: How are you inserting the table? Through the visual editor?

Comment: No through the text editor...

Comment: That is it :-). THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stray `<br>` tags after each of your table element tags. This is how your table code looks like in view source:

```
<table><br />
<tbody><br />
<tr><br />
<td colspan="3" width="623">Lean User Experience &amp; product Design</td><br />
</tr><br />
<tr><br />
<td width="417">Wprowadzenie do user experience design</td><br />
<td width="33">4h</td><br />
<td width="173">Iga Mościchowska</td><br />
...
```

`<br>` tags are not allowed inside `table` and `tr` elements. Only inside `td` elements are allowed.

Remove them.

**Update**:

It must be some sort of text filter in your Wordpress installation.

Remove the line breaks in the editor from between the tags. Let it all be in one line. For the table part only.

**Update 2:**

Or, after you have inserted the table through the text editor, switch back to the visual editor and save.

Comment: There are some weird stuff with Wordpress I hate, and this is one of them. Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You have loads of line breaks! If in the visual editor, simply remove the spacing, if it's hard coded, remove them from the code.

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/4dd145551502011261028e80138589c1

Answer (score 0):

Those gap you're referring to is actually a breaking space `<br><br/>`. There seem to be bug in your template.